# Make a redirect in a extend Http in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have set my own Http Service for settings my custom headers. 
I am trying to make a redirect when I got an error 401 but don't work, I don't know why. There is no error, the promise of `router.navigate` just return `false`. 
Am I doing something wrong ?

There is my `AuthHttpService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpService extends Http {

  constructor(
    backend: XHRBackend,
    options: RequestOptions,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
      if (!options) {
        // let's make option object
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    } else {
      // we have to add the token to the url object
      url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
  }

  private catchAuthError(self: AuthHttpService) {

    // we have to pass AuthHttpService's own instance here as `self`
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        // Redirect to logIn page if not authenticated
        this.router.navigate(['/logIn'])
        return Observable.empty();
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

And in app.module.ts I set :

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, router: Router) => {
        return new AuthHttpService(backend, options, router);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: post your router config, also, don't use an arrow function in a factory provider, it isn't supported and your prod builds will fail. Use a normal function.

Comment: Ooh thank you so much I haven't check in my routing ! My mistake was I have `canActivate: [UnAuthGuard]` on this route. When I remove that this worked. Thank you again !

Comment: no prob, check my comment edit though about your arrow function in your provider.

Comment: Thank you again bryan60 ;) Did you know if I have to delete my question ? Or If you want I can post my routing and you can write a short answer.

Comment: appreciate it but no worries. Idk if SO cares if you delete or not